# How can I remove myself from a Trello organization?

Tags: trello

I'm part of an organization on Trello, and would like to remove myself. How do I do so?

(This is a frequently asked question being posted by a member of the Trello team.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Suppose you'd joined the "Twilight Fan Club" organization on Trello ... but later decide that you don't actually like Twilight all that much, and would like to leave the organization.

1. Go to the organization page (https://trello.com/twilight)
2. Find your avatar in the list of members
3. Click on your avatar, and bring up this menu:

[image: Remove someone from an organization]

... and then click "Remove from Organization"

**Note:** Roughly the same process can be followed to remove yourself from a board.

Comment: It is good to know that if you created the organization, first you should add administration rights to somebody in the org, give up your admin rights, and then you can remove yourself from the organization.

Comment: this has been updated.  The list of members is now a vertical list and there's a leave button on the right side.

Comment: The "remove" word didn't do this upon clicking on it--something else (I don't remember what) did. I tried clicking that silly word for _minutes_ :p